# How to display all children of a table in Firebase - Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.android

How can I display all the children in this node called Games. This node has 4 children(four different auth users item key) and each child has got some data in them. The children are the id's of the authenticated users. In that sense, I have grouped every users data under the users item key.

`Auth.CurrentUser.Uid or user.uid gives me the data of just the current logged in user which is not what I want, but instead I want all data from all 4 children`

Now my question is, how can I display all data from all children?

This is my sample code

```
public void OnDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)
        {
            var items = snapshot.Child(mAuth.CurrentUser.Uid).Children?.ToEnumerable<DataSnapshot>();
            HashMap map;
            foreach (DataSnapshot item in items)
             {
              }

            //list items on listview
            adapter = new GameAdapter(peace_Hero,this);
            rv.SetLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            rv.SetItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            rv.SetAdapter(adapter);

            adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
            adapter.ItemClick += OnItemClick;

        }
```

Comment: Try this : `map = (HashMap)item.Value;` `var key = item.Key.ToString();`  `Hero.Add(new Hero(item.Key.ToString(),map.Get("Name")?.ToString(), map.Get("Achievement")?.ToString(),map.Get("History")?.ToString(),map.Get("Quote")?.ToString(), map.Get("Ref").ToString()));`

Comment: This is what i had but it wouldn't work. it just gives me values from the current logged in user